# Proper way to deal with fixture data in Python

Tags: python, fixtures

My program is producing natural language sentences.
I would like to test it properly by setting the random seed to a fix value and then:

- producing expected results;
- comparing generated sentences with expected results;
- if they differ, asking the user if the generated sentences were actually the expected results, and in this case, updating the expected results.

I already met such systems in JS, so I am surprised for not finding it in Python. How do you deal with such situations?

Comment: Do you mean something like [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: Not exactly but thanks this library looks really cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One drawback of asking the user to replace the expected answer is that the automated test can not be run automatically. Therefore, test frameworks do not allow reading from `input`.

I really wanted this feature, so my [implementation](https://github.com/guhur/nalgene/blob/master/tests/test_fixture.py) looks like:

```
def compare_results(expected, results):
    if not os.path.isfile(expected):
        logging.warning("The expected file does not exist.")
    elif filecmp.cmp(expected, results):
        logging.debug("%s is accepted." % expected)
        return 
    content = Path(results).read_text()
    print("The test %s failed." % expected)
    print("Should I accept the results?")
    print(content)
    while True:
        try:
            keep = input("[y/n]")
        except OSError:
            assert False, "The test failed. Run directly this file to accept the result"
        if keep.lower() in ["y", "yes"]:
            Path(expected).write_text(content)
            break
        elif keep.lower() in ["n", "no"]:
            assert False, "The test failed and you did not accept the answer."
            break
        else:
            print("Please answer by yes or no.")


def test_example_iot_root(setup):
    ...
    compare_results(EXPECTED_DIR / "iot_root.test", tmp.name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
    def istest(o):
        return isfunction(o[1]) and  o[0].startswith("test")

    [random.seed(1) and o[1](setup) for o in getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]) \
            if istest(o)]
```

When I run directly this file, it asks me whether or not it should replace the expected results. When I run from `pytest`, `input` creates an `OSError` that allows to quit the loop. Definitely not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There are many testing frameworks in Python, with two of the most popular being [PyTest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) and [Nose](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html). PyTest tends to cover all the bases, but Nose has a lot of nice extras as well.

With nose, [fixtures](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#fixtures) are covered early on in the docs. The example they give looks something like

```py
def setup_func():
    "set up test fixtures"

def teardown_func():
    "tear down test fixtures"

@with_setup(setup_func, teardown_func)
def test():
    "test ..."
```

In your case, with the manual review, you may need to build that logic directly into the test itself.

### Edit with a more specific example

Building on the example from Nose, one way you could address this is by writing the test

```py
from nose.tools import eq_

def setup_func():
    "set your random seed"

def teardown_func():
    "whatever teardown you need"

@with_setup(setup_func, teardown_func)
def test():
    expected = "the correct answer"
    actual = "make a prediction ..."
    _eq(expected, actual, "prediction did not match!")
```

When you run your tests, if the model does not produce the correct output, the tests will fail with "prediction did not match!". In that case, you should go to your test file and update `expected` with the expected value. This procedure isn't as dynamic as typing it in at runtime, but it has the advantage of being easily versioned and controlled.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to automatize this logic?

Comment: In researching an answer to that question, I found [this list](https://www.quora.com/How-is-Python-used-in-automation-testing-other-than-in-Selenium) with a bunch of other testing libraries which may meet your needs. My experience is primarily limited to automated testing frameworks, which by design do not usually allow user interaction. The "update" step you mention in the original question would probably best be handled by updating your tests directly. I will update my answer with an example.